# Extending Minkowski inequality to double summation?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

I know the Minkowski inequality for sequences as follows :
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k+y_k|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p\right)^{1/p}+\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|y_k|^p\right)^{1/p}$$

Now say we have $A=[a_{ij}], B=[b_{ij}]$, $n\times n$ matrices in $M(n,\mathbb{R})$, the vector space of all vectors of all real $n\times n$ matrices.  Can we extend this inequality to double summations, such as:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n|a_{ij}+b_{ij}|^p\right)^{1/p} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^p\right)^{1/p}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|b_{ij}|^p\right)^{1/p}$$

Comment: I think looking at matrix as a vector with length $n^2$ will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in fact, nothing has changed. What you have discovered is that the vector space

$$\text{Mat}_{n\times m}(\Bbb R)\cong \Bbb R^{mn}$$

of matrices of size $m\times n$ with coefficients in $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to an ordinary vector space, i.e. one of the form $\Bbb R^N$.

You are just quoting the usual Minkowski inequality where, instead of labeling the coordinates in your vector space with one index like $x_1,\ldots, x_{mn}$ (here the subscript $mn$ represents the single number $m\cdot n$, not two numbers) you decide to label the first $m$ with the sub index $(1,1), (1,2),\ldots (1,m)$ then the next $m$ by the sub-index $(2,1), (2,2),\ldots, (2,m)$ et cetera. But you've just relisted the order of the summands, you haven't changed the truth of the inequality.

In short, you haven't really extended it, you've just realized that you can juggle around the structure of your vector space so that it doesn't look immediately like $\Bbb R^N$, but it still is the same thing, just disguised.